# Setting up Network access for virtual ubuntu machine in Hyper V of windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualization

I installed Ubuntu 22.04(lastest) in windows server 2012 hyper V. i created an External virtual switch , but i couldnt manage to get internet for my virtual machine (ubuntu) and i couldnt make it accessable from the outside network.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me achive this.
thanks in advance.